# Construction: "Is also to do."

Tags: meaning, grammar, idioms, phrasal-verbs, semantics

This is a construction that lingered in the back of my mind for my entire life.

But for me "is to do" does not mean "has to do" as in:

> "Surely this is also to do with stagnating wages and a culture where
> saving for many is just impossible."

as I read it in the Guardian.

Dictionaries don't seem to have recorded something.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: I think that _to do with_ meaning 'concerning' or 'with regard to' is its own idiom in English and, while it's often (perhaps usually) paired with the verb _have_ and an indefinite object (_Does this have any/something to do with X?_), it can also appear by itself, as here, with different auxiliary verbs and no indefinite object at all. What's going on is that language is changing, and this construction is becoming frequent enough for you to notice it. If you don't like it, don't use it; but you can't control others' speech.

Comment: Lexico has "[be to do with](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/be_to_do_with)" so you might want to consult more dictionaries.

Comment: @StuartF Thanks for the reply people.  When it comes to dictionaries I have a set of 10 dictionaries or so. I consulted all of them. They had "be to do" and not "be to do with". I found it is too time consuming to look thorugh every small dictionary. But thanks.